# Mysql Fetch Assoc() Error

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/php-error-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

I am new in PHP, need some advice on the following code. I get the following error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wd\categories.php on line 42

PHP Code:

```
$SQL= "FROM  wdccat WHERE caid='$id' 
LEFT JOIN wdcat ON wdccat.caid = wdcat.ccid
LEFT JOIN wdclient ON wdccat.clid = wdclient.cid";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

((Line 42)) while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $str1;
echo $str2;
print $row['cid'];
echo $str3;
print $row['cid'];
echo $str4;
print $row['climage'];
echo $str5;
print $row['cname'];
echo $str6;
print $row['cid'];
echo $str7;
print $row['cname'];
echo $str8;
print $row['cid'];
echo $str9;
echo $str10;

}
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

The error i get with echo mysql_error();:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN wdcat ON wdccat.caid = wdcat.ccid LEFT JOIN wdclient ON wdccat.cl' at line 2
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wd\categories.php on line 42

Comment: Check your `$SQL` it is incorrect.

Comment: your query doesn't have SELECT

Answer (score 2):

You should check the result of `mysql_query()` for errors (returns `false`), eg

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
if (false === $result) {
    throw new Exception('Error in SQL query, you have: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

In your case, the query is malformed; You are missing the [`SELECT` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Some further advice; switch to the PDO library ASAP and start using [parameterised statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [bound parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Further reading here - http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1234522

Comment: Exactly. When running SQL code, there are two things you can't assume: "your query will succeed" and "input parameters will never contain single quotes".

Answer (score 0):

Try trowing a `echo mysql_error()` because theres something wrong with your query.

Probably because you are missing `SELECT *`

Answer (score -1):

Your $SQL is incomplete. It doesn't have the returned fields. Try:

```
$SQL= "SELECT wdclient.cid, climage, wdclient.cname FROM  wdccat WHERE caid='$id' 
LEFT JOIN wdcat ON wdccat.caid = wdcat.ccid
LEFT JOIN wdclient ON wdccat.clid = wdclient.cid";
```

This is assuming that `cid, climage, cname` comes from the same table.

Comment: No, the table wdccat has "id" "caid" "clid", table wdcat "ccid" "ccname" "ccdescription", table wdclient "cid" "cname" "ctel" "cfax".

Comment: Check it now. Don't know about climage...